# How should an aguna go about seeking a Gett?

Tags: how-to, divorce, aguna

If a woman is civilly divorced from her husband and needs her get, what resources are available to her?

I am completely out of my depth here. I would really appreciate this spelled out to me in plain English to assist my friend.

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya! Please consider [registering](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/login) your account, which will [give you access](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44557/why-should-i-register-my-account) to more of the site's features. Also, i think you're talking about a *mesurevet get*, someone who is denied a *get* by her husband. An *agunah* is a woman whose husband is unknown if he is dead or alive.

Comment: Wouldn't a mesurevet get be a subcategory of aguna?

Comment: @msh Did you leave the title intact on purpose?

Comment: @SkinnyJ You can define the categories however makes you happy.

Comment: @DoubleAA Even if not exactly accurate (which is arguable), it's colloquial, and is good for SEO.

Comment: @msh210 The body doesn't mention anything about "Aguna"-ness. For all it says the husband just hasn't thought abuot it yet.

Comment: @DoubleAA The first revision mentioned agunaness, but that includes the case he hasn't thought of it yet. I think it's fine as is; as always, anyone who disagrees should feel free to edit within site mores.

Answer (score 9):

A. Assuming she is in the United States, she should contact [the Beth Din of America](http://www.bethdin.org/contact.asp) and explain the situation to them. Most likely, upon understanding the predicament, they will issue a summons to her "husband." They also have experience with how to approach the husband in a way that's least likely to lead to a standoff.

B. **IF**, God forbid, that summons is not successful, then the Beth Din will publicize that he is found in contempt. At that point, an organization like ORA will mobilize community pressure or find other non-violent means to encourage him to do the right thing.

But Step One: Call (212) 807-9042.

Comment: Note that these instructions are valid in the opposite gender-direction as well.

Answer (score -1):

I'm sorry to hear about your friend's situation. There are organizations that help people like her. There are a bunch listed on the [Jewish Orthodox Feminist Alliance](http://www.jofa.org/Advocacy/Resources_for_Agunot).

If you are in the USA, a couple are:

- [ORA](http://www.getora.org/) -- Organization for the Resolution of Agunot
- [Agunah International](http://www.agunahinternational.com/)

There are more listened in the first link, including for USA, Canada, Israel, and England.

Comment: Agunah International utilizes halachic methods that many don't acknowledge. That leaves you on pretty shaky ground.

Comment: More broadly -- ORA will step in *only after* a beis din has made an effort. I don't know if that's the case here.

Comment: @cnsersmoit These organizations are there to help women who's husbands have refused to give a Get through standard channels. The questioner does not specify that that is the case.